# Create file form python in a user specified directory

Tags: python

I am checking if a file is present or not if present then append to that file if not create a new file.

I have done like below.

```
    if os.path.exists(test + '.csv'):
        system_file = open(test + '.csv', 'a')
        pass
    else:
        system_file = open(test + '.csv', 'w')
```

This is checking and creating files in default location `C:/users/viru/Desktop`. Is there a way to create these files in `C:/users/viru/testing/abc` directory

Comment: What does `test` variable contains?

Comment: @user1190882 list of tablenames

Comment: Of course: simply augment **test** to start with the desired directory path.

Comment: Note that, if **test** is a *list*, you need to iterate through the list.  The code you posted handles only one file at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a much *easier* way to do this. You are correct in thinking that if the `file` already exists, you don't want to `open` it with mode `'w'` as this will erase the contents. However, you can 'append' to an empty (new) `file` *as well as* a `file` which has already been created and has contents with the `'a'` (append) mode.

So you can just do:

```
system_file = open(test + '.csv', 'a')
```

without the `if-statements`, as even if `test` is a `path` to a `file` which hasn't yet been created, you can still now `write` to it even though it has been opened with the append (`'a'`) mode.

You can read more about the different `modes` that are accepted by the `open()` function [`here`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

Hope this is of use!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this using `os.path.join`.

I have used `H:\os` directory as my desired directory and `shovon` as my desired filename. Change it as your own input.

```
import os
test = os.path.join("H:",os.sep,"os","shovon")

if os.path.exists(test + '.csv'):
    system_file = open(test + '.csv', 'a')
    print("File already exists")
else:
    system_file = open(test + '.csv', 'w')
    print("New file is created")
```

The `os.sep` is used for adding separator sign based on your operating system. The path are concatenated as string and drive letter is with an extra colon as you see.